# Merge all .h264 files in directory in alphabetical order

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, video-editing

I have a camera that records in 5 second clips with filenames that are timestamps:

```
2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000000.h264
2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000001.h264
2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000002.h264
2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000003.h264
...
```

What is the easiest way to merge these in order into one video file on OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg's concat demuxer.

Create a text file listing the files in desired order. You can pipe the output of ls/dir to create it.

```
file 2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000000.h264
file 2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000001.h264
file 2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000002.h264
file 2017-03-08-09-54-27.334326-000003.h264
```

Then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

Comment: `ls *.h264 | sed -e 's/^/file /' > list.txt` if it helps anybody